# Handling PHP Sessions With Multiple Front End's

Tags: php, session, nginx, cluster-computing

We have **2x pfSense FW's** in HA, behind that, **2x Zen Load Balancers** in Master/Slave Cluster, behind those, **3x Front End web stack servers** running NGinx, PHP-FPM, PHP-APC. In that same network segment, there are **2x MySQL DB Servers** in Master/Slave replication.

> PHP sessions on the front ends should be "cleaned up" after 1440 seconds:
>
> > **session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440**

.

> Cookies are expired when the users browser closes:
>
> > **session.cookie_lifetime = 0**

Today, we were alerted by an end user that they logged in (PHP based login form on the website), but were authenticated as a completely different user. This is inconvenient to say the least.

The ZLB's are set to use Hash: Sticky Client. They should stick users to a single Front End (FE) for the duration of their session. The only reason I can think of this happening is that two of the FE's generated the same PHP Session ID, and then somehow the user was unlucky enough to be directed to that other FE by the LB's.

> My questions are plentiful, but for now, I only have a few:
>
> > 1. Could I perhaps set a different SESSID name per front end server? Would this stop the FE's generating session ID's that were the same? This would at least then result in the user getting logged out rather than logged in again as a different user!
> > 2. We sync the site data using lsyncd and a whole bunch of inotifywatch processes, but we do not sync the /var/lib/php directories that contain the sessions. I deliberately didn't do this... I'm now thinking perhaps I should be syncing that. lsyncd will be able to duplicate session files across all 3 front ends within about 10seconds of the sessions being modified. Good idea as a temporary fix?

Lastly, I know full well that the client should be using the DB to store sessions. This would completely eradicate it being able to duplicate the session ID's. But right now, they are unwilling to prioritise that in the development time-line.

Ideas very much welcome as I'm struggling to see an easy way out, even as a temporary measure. I cant let another client get logged in as a different user. It's a massive no-no.

Thanks!!

Comment: I've seen this problem in a company I've worked before, you would need to tell the load balancer to direct the traffic from a certain client to the same front-end server every time. If that doesn't help you could lock the sessions to a certain IP / User agent / a cookie identifying the front end server, and destroy the session if it doesn't match.

Comment: @Cesar: Dave said he's already doing this. But its the *wrong* way to solve the problem.

Comment: @symcbean I also pointed out that he could add a cookie identifying the front end server being used. It would still drop the session, but it would prevent it from giving it to the wrong user.

Comment: @DaveByrne Do you have access to the PHP logic?

Comment: @Cesar: you're digging a hole here. All the information except for a cookie provided by the client can potentially and validly change during the session (IP address, SSL session, even user-agent). The *only* way to implement reliable sticky sessions (i.e. a 1:1 association between clients and servers) is by cookie. But sticky sessions are never the right way to solve a problem.

Comment: @symcbean No, I'm not. I'm am merely stating that if the application disregards the session ID from a different server based on the cookie indicating it was created by a different server the session will NOT leak to the other front end servers. It will just lock the user out of their session, which is obviously no longer theirs.

Comment: So you are describing a solution to the problem where 2 servers generate the same session id. If so, then 1) that's Dave's *suspicion* and not based on any evidence 2) if that proved to be the case, then wouldn't it be simpler to fix the PHPSESSID generation?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your question you are somewhat confused by the problem - and its not clear exactly what problem you are trying to fix.

> Today, we were alerted by an end user that they logged in (PHP based login form on the website), but were authenticated as a completely different user

There's potentially several things happening here.

> Cookies are expired when the users browser closes:

Not so. Depending on how the browser is configured, most will retain session cookies across restarts. Since this is controlled at the client, its not something you can do much about.

> PHP sessions on the front ends should be "cleaned up" after 1440 seconds

The magic word here is "after" - garbage collection is triggered on a random basis. Session files can persist for much longer and the *default* handler will happily retrieve and unserialize session data after the TTL has expired.

Do you control the application code? (if not, your post is off-topic here). If so, then its possible you have session fixation and hijack vulnerabilities in your code (but that's based on the description provided by the user - which is typically imprecise and misleading).

Its also *possible* that content is being cached somewhere in the stack inappropriately.

You didn't say if the site is running on HTTP, HTTPS or mixed, and if HTTPS is involved, where the SSL is terminated. These are key to understanding where the issue may have arisen.

Your next steps are to ensure that:

1. you have logout functionality in your code which destroys the session data *and* changes the session id
2. that you change the session id on authentication
3. That your session based scripts are returning appropriate caching information (including a Varies: Cookie header)
   It is *highly* improbable that 2 systems would generate the same session id around the same time.

Really you want to get away from using sticky sessions. It's not hard.

You've got **2 layers** at your front end that are adding no functional or performance value, and since you are using sticky sessions, effectively no capacity or resillience value!!! Whoever sold you this is laughing all the way to the bank.

Comment: Hi symcbean, thanks for the reply :) We are the service provider, we spec'd and designed the entire stack. It is similar to many we have provisioned prior to this also. The 2 layers in front of the web servers definitely do add function (and by proxy performance seeing as the LB's are sharing the load across 3 web servers). The infrastructure is highly resilient, that's the main thing, the secondary FW's and LB's are located elsewhere. The entire infrastructure is then additionally sync'd in HA to another country, with live failover setup.

Comment: That being said, I appreciate your information on the session side of the question. Unfortunately, the code is developed in house with the client, we simply provide the managed infrastructure it sits in. I am in the process of deploying a memcached server within the clients environment. And I will configure PHP on the 3x Front End servers to store sessions in the memcached object cache.